# Polar Bubble Chart

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, charts, scripting

I would like to create a plot similar to that in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDSYP.png). I tried using both ListPolarPlot and BubbleChart, but they do not have the right option for creating a polar bubble chart. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the data is formatted as {theta, r, size, temperature}

```
SeedRandom[1234]
n = 10;
data = Transpose@{
    RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n] (* theta *),
    RandomReal[{0, 10}, n] (* radius *),
    RandomReal[{1, 5}, n] (* size *),
    RandomReal[{6000, 8000}, n] (* temperature *)};

labels = {None, "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", None, None, "J"};

{minSize, maxSize} = MinMax[data[[All, 3]]];
{minBubble, maxBubble} = {6, 25};

{minTemp, maxTemp} = MinMax[data[[All, 4]]];

Legended[
 ListPolarPlot[
  List /@
   (Labeled @@@ Transpose[{data[[All, 1 ;; 2]], labels}]),
  PlotStyle -> (Directive[
       AbsolutePointSize[Rescale[#[[1]],
         {minSize, maxSize},
         {minBubble, maxBubble}]],
       ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#[[2]],
         {minTemp, maxTemp}]]] & /@
     data[[All, 3 ;; 4]]),
  PolarAxes -> True,
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {5, 10}},
  PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 360 Degree, 90 Degree], {5, 10}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]],
 BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {minTemp, maxTemp}},
  LegendLabel -> Subscript[Style["T", Italic], "eff"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Just one little thing... the color of each data point should be related with the temperature, as the data are {theta, r, size, temperature}.

Comment: Edited. In the future provide sample data and explain in words what you want. A plot "similar" to a linked plot is not descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ListPolarPlot` and change the marker size. But if you want it to look as close as possible to that plot then you may need to build it up manually with `Graphics` elements. Here is something I made to get you started. Hopefully you or somebody interested can improve it and build a more flexible chart that works with a variety of data and plot ranges *( remove the magic numbers )*:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
grayPos = RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, 10], 50];
grayRadii = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[5], 50];
grayDisks = MapThread[Disk[#1, #2] &, {grayPos, grayRadii}];

tempcol[temp_] := 
 ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", "Reverse"}][
  Rescale[Clip[temp, {6000, 8000}], {6000, 8000}]]
datapoint[radius_, temp_, angle_, distance_, label_] := 
 Block[{pos = {Cos[angle], Sin[angle]}*distance},
  {EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[tempcol[temp]], Disk[pos, radius], 
   Text[Style[label, tempcol[temp], FontFamily -> "Arial", 
     FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 14], pos + radius*{-3/2, 3/2}]}]

data = {{1, 6200, -45 Degree, 7.5, "CoRoT-3b"},
   {.8, 7800, 5 Degree, 4.8, "HATS-70b"}};

Graphics[{
  {Opacity[.1], grayDisks},
  {Opacity[.1], Disk[{0, 0}, 12, {\[Pi]/8, -\[Pi]/8}]},
  {Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 12]},
  {Thin, Opacity[.5], Darker@Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 10]},
  {Thin, Opacity[.5], Darker@Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 5]},
  MapThread[
   Text[Style[#1, FontFamily -> "Courier", FontWeight -> Bold, 
      FontSize -> 18], #2] &, {{"5", "10"}, {{-4, 0}, {-9, 0}}}],
  {Line[{{0, -12}, {0, 12}}]},
  {Line[{{0, 0}, {12, 0}}]},
  {datapoint @@@ data},
  MapThread[
   Text[Style[#1, FontFamily -> "Courier", FontWeight -> Bold, 
      FontSize -> 18], #2] &, {{"90\[Degree]", 
     "a/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(\[Star]\)]\) ", "270\[Degree]", 
     "0\[Degree]"}, CirclePoints[{13, \[Pi]/2}, 4]}]
  }, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: polar bubbles]

Answer (score 4):

Using `data` from Bob Hanlon's answer:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
n = 10;
data = Transpose@{RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n], RandomReal[{0, 5}, n], 
    RandomReal[{1, 5}, n], RandomReal[1, n]};
```

Pre-process `data` into a form that can be used with `BubbleChart`:

```
bc = BubbleChart[{Append[#2 {Cos@#, Sin@#}, #3]} & @@@ data, 
   BubbleSizes -> {0.05, 0.1}, 
   ChartStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[data[[All, 4]]]), 
   Frame -> False,
   ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[ToString /@ data[[All, 3 ;;]], 
     LegendMarkers -> "Bubble", 
     LegendLayout -> (TableForm[Join[List /@ #[[All, 1]], data, 2], 
       TableHeadings -> {None, {"", "θ", "r", "Y", "Z"}}, TableAlignments -> Center] &)]]
```

[image]

To add polar axes/ticks/gridlines use  `ListPolarPlot` with desired options:

```
lpp = ListPolarPlot[MinMax[data[[All, 2]]], 
   PlotStyle -> None,
   PolarAxes -> {True, True}, 
   PolarTicks -> {{0 , 90, 180, 270} Degree /. 
      180 Degree -> {180 Degree, Row[{a, Subscript[R, "*"]}, "/"]}, 
     Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> Automatic];

Show[lpp, bc, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution.